# Delete last row of each subset in a list

Tags: r

I have a list containing several data frames. I would like to delete the last row of each data frame in the list. I used

```
sapply(list.name,function(d){d<- d[-nrow(d),]})
```

but it does not work. Does anyone know how I can do this.

Comment: Perhaps something along the lines of: `d<- d[1:nrow(d)-1,]`.  Could you post an example for us of a list with the dfs in to make it easier to develop and test a solution?

Comment: I got my answer. I should have used lapply. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
lapply(list.name,head,-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You were close, no need for assignement inside your function.

```
newlist <- lapply(dflist, function(d) d[-nrow(d), ])
```

This is a more general solution that you can adapt to other problems but in this case @textb solution  more efficient.

Comment: That would also do it, but I guess that the aoproach of @Nazanin would also have led to the intented result with `lapply()` instead of `sapply()`, because the `d <- ...` assignment would (invisibly) return its value.

Comment: Perfectly worked. Now I know the difference between lapply and sapply. Thank you @textb and dickoa.